# Replace elements in associative array if value is not numeric

Tags: php, arrays, replace, associative-array

I have an associative array like this:

```
$list = array("key1"=>3,"key2"=>5,"key3","key4"=>2);
```

When I print the value of $list, I get the following:

```
Array ( [key1] => 3 
        [key2] => 5 
        [0] => key3 
        [key4] => 2 )
```

What is the best way to check that each key in the array has been filled with an integer, and set it with a default value of 1 if it hasn't got a value yet?

So the final result for the above array after the check should be:

```
Array ( [key1] => 3 
        [key2] => 5 
        [key3] => 1
        [key4] => 2 )
```

Comment: You could loop over it and check if the value is numeric, if not add a 1.. Take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: `check that each key in the array has been filled with an integer` this line should be `check that each vallue in the array has been filled with an integer`

Comment: This seems like an odd scenario.  Why is your input so poorly structured in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $list = array("key1"=>3,"key2"=>5,"key3","key4"=>2);

   foreach($list as $k => $v) {
        if(!is_int($v)) {
            unset($list[$k]);
            $list[$v] = 1;
        }
   }

   ksort($list);

   print_r($list);
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean check, if all values of array are integers

```
$is_all_integer = array_filter($list, function($v){return is_int($v);}) === $list;
```

If not all values are integer, then setting default value 1

```
if(!$is_all_integer)
    $list = array_map(function(&$v){return is_int($v) ? $v : 1;}, $list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$list = array("key1"=>3,"key2"=>5,"key3","key4"=>2);

foreach($list as $key=> $value)
{
    if(is_numeric($key))
    {
        unset($list[$key]);
        $list[$value] = 1;
    }

}

ksort($list);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```

if you need example then refer the link https://ideone.com/n2ihA0